# How to grant user access to one table in a specific schema in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Logged in as the superuser, how can I grant user access to a specific table under a specific schema.

I tried this

GRANT SELECT on TABLE this_schema.my_table TO my_user

But when I login as my_user I can't select from the table. I don't want my_user to have access to any other tables in this_schema.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to grant usage on the schema as well

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA this_schema TO GROUP my_user;
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes its possible.
You can use following command, to give select access of specific table to specific user.

```
GRANT SELECT on SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME TO USER_NAME;
```

NOTE: user still list and describe other tables in the given schema.

Comment: is there any way to restrict user from seeing , listing and describing other tables in the given schema . Consider i have a common schema "sales " and i have two users ( UserX & UserY) who have access to the schema . At any point of time UserX or UserY should able to view, access & list only tables that are created by them. is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Without creating user group, you can do:

`GRANT SELECT ON TABLE my_table IN SCHEMA this_schema TO my_user;`

Comment: running this in redshift console editor throws this syntax error: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "IN" Position: 44`